# Is there any performance benefit from caching the document object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, caching, dom-traversal

I tend to cache DOM objects used in a given script but recently found myself having to call the `document` object within a jQuery wrapper. I was wondering if caching `$(document)` was even worth it considering that there's only one `document` object per page, which would essentially limit the lookup to one.

Although you're **caching** it, I'm curious as far as the overall gain if it's called multiple times. I know I'm getting a bit technical but wonder if its more effort on the browser's part to create the variable reference than explicitly writing it out to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any performance benefit from caching the document object?

Technically yes, but not enough of one to "mandate" caching it for performance reasons. I say "technically" because there *is* an object allocation and a little bit of logic involved with wrapping the `document` object as a jQuery object, but it's very cheap. As long as you aren't wrapping it hundreds or thousands of times, just go with whatever makes the code cleaner.

Comment: My rule is, if I'm doing it in a loop, I usually want to consider caching it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you say that this would also apply to `body` just as much?

Comment: @CarlEdwards yes. In general if you have easy access to a DOM node, wrapping it in a jQuery object is very cheap.